# Using jenkins and docker to deploy to server

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

Hey I am currently  learn Jenkins pipeline for CI and CD
I was successfully deploy my express js by Jenkins 
On locally machine my server
It was for server and my ENV was show off on my public  repository 
I am here trying to understand more how to hide that ENV on my Jenkins? That use variable 
And is that possible to use variable on Dockerfile also to hide my ENV ?

On my Jenkins Pipeline 
I run my ENV on docker run -p -e myEnV=key 
I do love to hide my ENV so people didn't know my keys inside on my Jenkinsfile and Dockerfile 
I am using multi branches in jenkins because I follow the article on hackernoon for deploy react and node js app with Jenkins

And anyway, what advantages  to push our container or image to Docker  Hub? 
If we push it to there and if we want to move our server to another server
We just need to pull our repo Docker Hub to use that to new server because what we have been build everytime it push to our repo Docker Hub  , right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, you should use [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). or If you are running Docker from the pipeline, then set Environment variable in Jenkins, then access these environment variables in Docker run command.

in the pipeline, you can access environment variable like this

`${env.DEVOPS_KEY}`
So your Docker run command will be

```
docker run -p -e myEnV=${env.DEVOPS_KEY}
```

But make sure you have set `DEVOPS_KEY` in the Jenkins server.

Using EnvInject it pretty much simple.

[image]

You can also inject from the file.

[image]

For your Second Question, Yes just the pull the image from docker-hub and use it.

Anyone from your Team can pull and run so only the Jenkins server will build and push the image. So it will save time for others and the image will be up to date and will also available remotely.

Never push or keep sensitive data in your Docker image.

Comment: For EnvInject,  we just create a folder on our machine ? With that key ? Like say we path that folder to ~/Documents/myapp/the key , is that you mean ? And is that o my can do by freestyle job or multibranche ?

Comment: Yes one way to put in file or one to way to set at job liken in screen shots

Comment: @popes did this help?

Comment: I did , anyway, how can we deploy to multi server in jenkins, let say I want to the master branch deploy to local server and branch Dev to another server ? Is that possible in one job do that?

Comment: yes it possible, when job is trigger from bitbucket or github check the branch, if the branch is `development` then do deploy on development or if master then prod.

Comment: Do we need to use pipeline for that??

Comment: You can use bash or pipline but better to use pipline with generic webhhook plugin

Answer (score 0):

Using Docker Hub or any kind of registry like Sonatype Nexus, Registry, JFrog Artifactory helps you to keep your images with their tags and share it with anyone. It also means that the images are safe there. If your local environment goes down, the images will stay there. It also helps for version control. If you are using multibranch pipelines, that means that you probably will generate different images with different tags.

Running Jenkins, working the jobs, doing the deployment is not a good practice. In my experience from previous work, the best exaples are: The server starts being bloated after some time, Jenkins doesn't work the most important times that you need it, The application you have deployed does not work because Jenkins has too many jobs that takes all the resources.

Currently, I am running different servers for Jenkins Master and Slave. Master instance does not run any jobs, only the master instances do. This keeps Jenkins alive all the time. If slaves goes down, you can simply set another slave.

For deployment, I am using Ansible which can simultaneously deploy the same docker image to multiple servers. It is easy to use and in my opinion quite safe as well.

For the sensitive data such as keys, password, api keys, you are right about using `-e` flag. You can also use `--env-file`. This way, you can keep it outside of docker image and keep the file. For passwords, I prefer to have a shell script that generates the passwords in environment files.

If you are planning to use the environment as it is, you can keep the value that you are going to set as environment variable inside Jenkins safely. then you can get that value as a variable. You can see it in [Jenkins website](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/)

Comment: I am running Jenkins on docker compose,  do we need to configuration for master and slave Jenkins on our server ? Or it will automatically config when we use Jenkins on my docker compose??